# How do I remove the ADs in uTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

Since version 3.2, uTorrent displays ADs in the form of a "Featured Torrent" banner and a small square advertising in the sidebar. Is there a way to disable those?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the following settings to `false` in the advanced settings of uTorrent. Some variable names differ depending on your uTorrent version:

- `bt.enable_pulse`
- `gui.show_notorrents_node`
- `gui.show_plus_upsell`
- `offers.content_offer_autoexec`
- `offers.left_rail_offer_enabled` / `left_rail_offer`
- `offers.sponsored_torrent_offer_enabled` / `sponsored_torrent_offer_enabled`

[image: Preferences Dialog]

Source : [Lifehacker - How to Disable Ads in uTorrent](http://lifehacker.com/disable-ads-in-utorrent-via-settings-826283231)

Answer (score 4):

### To disable the sidebar AD:

- Click on "Options" -> Show information about Plus

### To disable the "featured" banner:

- Click on the "Preferences" icon (upper right)
- Clik on the "advanced" tab
- Change the value of `sponsored_torrent_offer_enabled` to `false`.
- Restart uTorrent.

([source](http://torrentfreak.com/utorrent-is-now-ad-supported-and-how-to-disable-121111/))