# How do I remove Ads in *new* Utorrent 3.3.2?

Tags: utorrent, advertisements

How do I remove this pesky ad bar in Utorrent? I already removed most of these idiotic messages, with the help of [How do I remove the ADs in uTorrent?](https://superuser.com/questions/619494/how-do-i-remove-the-ads-in-utorrent), but one remains:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also: set the value to `false` for:

```
offers.left.rail_offer_enabled
```

and restart the program.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the steps at the link you provided and my uTorrent is ad-free now. To remove that you have to change the value of `sponsored_torrent_offer_enabled` to `false`. To do that:

- Ctrl+P : Preferences and go to Advanced tab
- From the list set `offers.sponsored_torrent_offer` value to `false`.
- Restart uTorrent and it is gone.

That worked for me, should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, newer versions of uTorrent does not support full ad-removal functions (as before), this time you can [remove ads from uTorrent](http://www.softblogger.net/remove-ads-utorrent/) which are not related to their uTorrent Plus service.

I would recommend you to search for these options under Advanced tab in uTorrent Properties window:

- Type in `sponsored` in the Filter field and set the value to `false` for the only available;
- Type in `upsell` in the same field and set it to `false`;

You can also remove annoying bundle offers by `right-clicking` on the blue icon from the left side of the application and choose `Hide Featured Content` option from the menu.

Additionally, to remove Recommended tab at the bottom simply `right click` on the tabs and un-check the Recommended tab.