# How to disable ads in uTorrent for MacOS

Tags: macos, utorrent, advertisements

How to disable ads in uTorrent for Mac OS?

[screenshot: uTorrent mac with ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Zhf.png)

That's not a duplicate of [How do I remove the ADs in uTorrent?](https://superuser.com/questions/619494/how-do-i-remove-the-ads-in-utorrent) because this question is about MacOS version, which have different settings and ads hosts. Reciple from that question is useless for MacOS version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the ADs in uTorrent?](https://superuser.com/questions/619494/how-do-i-remove-the-ads-in-utorrent)

Comment: No. Because MacOS uTorrent differs from Windows version.

Comment: Isn't there any preferences option in uTorrent? Windows has Ctrl+P shortcut to open preferences.

Comment: uTorrent Mac looks completely rewritten from scratch. It is not ported version. Here is preferences screen: https://imgur.com/a/BiDqAFt

Answer (score 6):

We need to prevent access to ads hosts and clear cache

## 0. Close uTorrent

To close it completely open uTorrent and press ⌘+q

## 1. Put this into your hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 cdn.bitmedianetwork.com
127.0.0.1 static.ap.bittorrent.com
127.0.0.1 www.bt.co
127.0.0.1 bt.co
```

Use `sudo nano /etc/hosts` for it. ([How to do it?](https://www.imore.com/how-edit-your-macs-hosts-file-and-why-you-would-want))

## 2. Clear uTorrent cache

Open Terminal and execute

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.bittorrent.uTorrent
```